# Chess puzzles in newspapers and magazines which offer a prize

Tags: puzzles

I like chess puzzles, and particularly like those for which there is a prize.

*The Times*, *Sunday Times* and *Spectator* provide weekly puzzles (I'm based in the UK). These puzzles are available online as well as printed. I can usually answer two of these and, in good week, all three.

I'd like to know of other sources of chess puzzles in the press or on the web which offer a modest reward. Do you know of any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one I am aware of is [chesspuzzles.com](http://www.chesspuzzles.com/) offering a prize drawing for:

- Mate in 1 problem: *Chess Rules for Students* (RRP $4.50)
- Mate in 2 problem: *Checkmate! Ideas for Students* (RRP $5.00)
- Mate in 3 problem: *Chess Tactics for Students* (RRP $16.00, but on sales for $12.80 now)

All prizes written by John Bain. The latest prize drawing was week ending Saturday 16-December-2016, at the time of answering this post.